# Get ip address of source in mysql general query log?

Tags: mysql, database

Is there some way for me to identify which server is doing an sql insert along with the details of the query? I don't know where my inserts are coming from and would like to identify the source

Comment: you have to use front end coding for it....without coding you can not check......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP, then;

Here is the code to display your ip address.

```
$ip=@$REMOTE_ADDR;
echo "<b>IP Address= $ip</b>";
```

**IP address if the register_global is off**

If at `php.ini` if register_global is set to Off then we have to change the script a bit to get the address. Here it is

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

> The IP address from which the user is
>   viewing the current page.

Note that changing register global setting my be a security problem particularly in live hosting environment so consult your host before in this aspects also.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php